# Signing AWS HTTP requests with Apache HttpComponents Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, apache-httpcomponents, elasticsearch-jest

I'm trying to make HTTP requests to an [AWS Elasticsearch](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) domain protected by an IAM access policy. I need to [sign](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) these requests for them to be authorized by AWS.
I'm using [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest), which in turn use [Apache HttpComponents Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).

This seems to be a common use case, but I can't find what should I do so Jest can sign all requests.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I found it! :)

This project seems to do exactly what I want : [aws-signing-request-interceptor](https://github.com/inreachventures/aws-signing-request-interceptor), described as *"Request Interceptor for Apache Client that signs the request for AWS. Originally created to support AWS' Elasticsearch Service using the Jest client."*.

Edit : I [forked the project](https://github.com/ericcitaire/aws-signing-request-interceptor) to fit my needs (Java 7, temporary STS credentials), and it works nicely.

Here is an example of usage (here without STS temporary credentials):

```
String region = "us-east-1";
String service = "es";
String url = "???"; // put the AWS ElasticSearch endpoint here

DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain awsCredentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
final AWSSigner awsSigner = new AWSSigner(awsCredentialsProvider, region, service, () -> new LocalDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC));

JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory() {
    @Override
    protected HttpClientBuilder configureHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder builder) {
        builder.addInterceptorLast(new AWSSigningRequestInterceptor(awsSigner));
        return builder;
    }
};
factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig.Builder(url)
        .multiThreaded(true)
        .build());
JestClient client = factory.getObject();
```

Comment: Hi Eric I am following the github link provided by you. We are facing the forbidden error. Another question is in normal jest client we pass elastic search endpoint. But here we are passing only service name and region. Can you provide sample code or guidance to solve our problem.

Comment: Hi @MohanShanmugam. The forbidden error is probably due to access policy misconfiguration or bad credentials. I added an example of usage in the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Eric thanks for reply. We use jestclient to create index, put mapping and insert records in this index creation and delete index are working fine. Put mapping and insert records shows forbidden error. When I go through all community members discussions it's look weird. We are using jest 2.0.0 and AWS Es 2.3. Do you have any clue why put mapping and insert records not works.

Comment: We are running this program from AWS lambda. The lambda role have Es full permissions. We used this role ARN in elastic search policy.

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot this for you without knowing the details. You should post your issue in AWS forums or contact the support. They are both of great help.

Comment: Thanks for the support i had solved this issue. Its an AWS issue

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Got `{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details ...` error with that. It means that signature is not correct. :(

Comment: @Cherry check [the related documentation about this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html). In particular, check that the region and the endpoint are correct.

Comment: @Eric Citaire . I am using your same appoach. But in my case i want to use STS credentials. Is there a way we can retrieve the STS credentials ? In my ES policy i have added account level access

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work in case of Async request.

Update:

Ignore my previous comment. It works after adding interceptor for async requests too:

```
final AWSSigningRequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new AWSSigningRequestInterceptor(awsSigner);
            factory = new JestClientFactory() {
                @Override
                protected HttpClientBuilder configureHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder builder) {
                    builder.addInterceptorLast(requestInterceptor);
                    return builder;
                }
                @Override
                protected HttpAsyncClientBuilder configureHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder builder) {
                    builder.addInterceptorLast(requestInterceptor);
                    return builder;
                }
            };
```