# Spring Boot Elastic Search And Not Able to Connect

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I was following this tutorial on  the Mkyong site
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-elasticsearch-example/

It uses the spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch library to connect to elasticSearch

I was using the following details to try and connect to an elastic search instance on Amazon`

```
elasticsearch.host=<search address in amazon elastic search console>
elasticsearch.port=9200
elasticsearch.clustername=<accountId:clusterName>`
```

However I keep getting the following errors

```
 2017-05-16 18:37:24.308  INFO 7108 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=esConfig; factoryMethodName=elasticsearchTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mkyong/EsConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=elasticsearchTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]]
2017-05-16 18:37:24.859  INFO 7108 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.plugins                : [Rawhide Kid] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017-05-16 18:37:46.911  INFO 7108 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.client.transport       : [Rawhide Kid] failed to connect to node [{#transport#-1}{55.66.223.158}{55.66.223.158:9200}], removed from nodes list

org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][55.66.223.158:9200] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannelsLight(NettyTransport.java:967) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:933) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNodeLight(NettyTransport.java:906) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLight(TransportService.java:267) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:390) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:336) [elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.addTransportAddresses(TransportClientNodesService.java:187) [elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.addTransportAddress(TransportClient.java:243) [elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.mkyong.EsConfig.client(EsConfig.java:45) [classes/:na]
    at com.mkyong.EsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e0ccfee.CGLIB$client$0(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at com.mkyong.EsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e0ccfee$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$83a2b819.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) [spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.mkyong.EsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e0ccfee.client(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instant
```

Any ideas what I need to do to connect to an elastic search instance on Amazon?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: can you call elasticsearch endpoint from local `curl -XGET 55.66.223.158:9200` from you local or not?

Comment: I can curl to port 80 but not port 9200 or port 9300

Comment: Does port 80 return elasticsearch info or simply http response? I mean what is the response of `curl -XGET 55.66.223.158:80`. I just wanted to make sure that elasticsearch on your remote machine runs on port 9200, and AWS has firewall open for that port.

Comment: This is the response of curl on port 80 - {
  "name" : "Mimir",
  "cluster_name" : "<my cluster name>",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.2",
    "build_hash" : "72aa8010df1a4fc849da359c9c58acba6c4d9518",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-11-14T15:59:50Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: so its running on port 80, but you are connecting to 9200. change your config, `elasticsearch.port=80`. should work

Comment: that gives me this error - java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (48,54,54,50)

Comment: There are few reasons why `StreamCorruptedException` happens. Can you check your java running on elasticsearch server and your local machine are same? - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-internal-transport-message-format-got-3-41-4d-52/25247/3

Comment: The other reason would be port `80` is be equivalent to `9200` which is default port for http communication for elasticsearch. But there used to be port `9300` for TCP connection from api like Java. I am not what sure what port Amazon runs for tcp transportation. Please check AWS elasticsearch config for that - http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Failing-starting-due-to-transport-layer-exception-td4033399.html

Comment: Nevermind it would be port 80 for TCP communication as well, as this [answer mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33558330/432903). so check java versions are similar in server and client, BUT also make sure your clustername is right

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elasticsearch doesn't support TCP connections, only HTTP connections. This explains why your CURL commands work, but your java connection doesn't work.

```
TCP transport
The service supports HTTP on port 80, but does not support TCP transport.
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-resources.html

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=683536

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elasticsearch only works on port 80 using Rest API. The default transport API from elasticsearch does not work with Hosted AWS elasticsearch.

I had to customize the [Jest client](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest) to add additional hooks to sign every request.

You may want to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760144/signing-aws-http-requests-with-apache-httpcomponents-client/43550224#43550224) post on Stack Overflow for more details on how to sign the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Use HOST: ip address of hosted AWS elasticsearch or path of hosted AWS es and PORT : 80

Ex:

10.100.1.1 or xyz.abc.com