# AWS Elasticsearch: Signing requests made by elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

We are using [elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/6.2.2) to communicate with AWS Elasticsearch.

But, as we are told, we need to sign requests with AWS credentials. I am aware of the class `AWS4Signer`, but don't know how can I use it with `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client`.

Comment: This should get you going: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760144/signing-aws-http-requests-with-apache-httpcomponents-client

Answer (score 0):

From the aws [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html)

```
public static RestHighLevelClient esClient(String serviceName, String region) {
    AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
    signer.setServiceName(serviceName);
    signer.setRegionName(region);
    HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = new AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor(serviceName, signer, credentialsProvider);
    return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(aesEndpoint)).setHttpClientConfigCallback(hacb -> hacb.addInterceptorLast(interceptor)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [a new maintained fork](https://github.com/acm19/aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor) of the archived aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor. It was upgraded to AWS SDK 2, and has a number of bug fixes, such as supporting retries. It contains a working example of how to talk to Amazon OpenSearch (Elasticsearch). Version 2.1.1 was just released to Maven central.